# How to restore deleted azure resource groups

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-resource-group

One of my resource groups has been deleted by mistake. I am unable to find any option in the azure portal to restore it. Is there any option available to restore deleted resource groups?

Comment: I dont think so. however you can lock your RGs related to prod

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there any option available to restore deleted resource groups?

Directly, there's no method to restore deleted resource groups. One thing you could do is create a new resource group and find the deployment template used to create resource in the deleted resource group. You can then use that template to recreate the resources.

For future reference, you should lock your resource groups with "CANNOT DELETE" lock to prevent accidental deletes.

Comment: There is no way to find or access the deployment templates for a resource group once that resource group has been deleted.

Comment: Agreed! However I'm assuming that these templates are stored somewhere on premises as they can be reused.

Comment: They'll only have them if they used an ARM Template deployment in the first place. If they manually deployed through the portal or command-line then they wont have an "original" template.

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that if the resources were created through the portal, then in theory you would (preemptively) be able to export templates per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/export-template-portal, modify them as necessary, and store them offline somewhere, e.g. in a GitHub repository, and implement a build pipeline in Azure or use GitHub Actions or something similar.

Then in the event you need to restore a resource group, you can redeploy start to redeploy the build pipeline in which those ARM templates will recreate the Azure Resource Group and or Resources. This process is referred to CI/DC (Continuous Integration/Continuous Delivery)

Some references:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline?view=azure-devops&tabs=java%2Ctfs-2018-2%2Cbrowser
- https://docs.github.com/en/actions